# How to render DistanceJoint

Tags: flutter, dart, box2d, flame, forge2d

I need to render a DistanceJoint, just a line connecting the 2 anchors, nothing fancy. I've seen something about a render method [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/forge2d/latest/forge2d_browser/DistanceJoint/render.html) but I coulen't figure out how to use it. I also don't mind using debug features. Thank you very much :)

Comment: can you please add more detail, maybe show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged the question with Flame I'm guessing that you are using `flame_forge2d`?

The link that you provide is for pure forge2d web, but you should be able to do it in a similar fashion in `flame_forge2d`.
I would try something like this in your `Forge2DGame`:

```dart
  final _bodyARenderPosition = Vector2.zero();
  final _bodyBRenderPosition = Vector2.zero();

  @override
  void render(Canvas c) {
    super.render(c);
    c.save();
    c.scale(camera.zoom);
    for (final joint in world.joints) {
      _bodyARenderPosition
        ..setFrom(joint.bodyA.position)
        ..y *= -1;
      _bodyBRenderPosition
        ..setFrom(joint.bodyB.position)
        ..y *= -1;
      c.drawLine(
        _bodyARenderPosition.toOffset(),
        _bodyBRenderPosition.toOffset(),
        debugPaint,
      );
    }
    c.restore();
  }
```

Comment: Hmm... drawLine is called on the correct joints but I can't see any lines. Also, debugPaint is white while the background is black and the positions of bodyA/B is different.

Comment: Here's a link to my code, it's bad I know  https://github.com/adamkatav/sipl_client/blob/main/lib/game.dart

Comment: It looks like you might be using a quite old version of flame_forge2d, try to invert the y-axis of a cloned version of the body position before drawing the line. (Or update to a newer version of `flame_forge2d`, but then you'll have some other things to sort out first since there has been breaking changes).

Comment: Updating didn't help but inverting the Y exis did Thank you very much! Why did it work?

Comment: No problem! :)
Right, because here we are looking directly at the body positions that are coming from `Forge2D` and not on the `BodyComponent` positions, `Forge2D` is using a flipped coordinate system, where Y is shrinking downwards instead of growing like it is on the canvas, that's why the positions have to be flipped when rendered.

Comment: Updated the code to include the flip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246591/discussion-between-adam-katav-and-spydon).

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to write that, though I do have another question if that's okay